# Extract substring from a log message (GROK)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I am new to ELK and I have this log message:

```
[2020-07-14 13:46:40.812],[DEBUG],[PerformanceLogger],[10.11.12.13],[http-nio-8086-exec-1],[3808B7],1,[2ddf8d01-4e5b-42cf-a6d9-ac2c0a24ccf5],[],[],[],[],[],REQUEST_END,125
```

I want to extract the number `125` - this number appears *only* if, before it, there is this exact string:

`'REQUEST_END,'`

(I want to call this field: duration)

This is what I did so far... but it does not work:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { 
      "message" => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:alis_timestamp}\],\[%{LOGLEVEL:alis_loglevel}\s*\],\[%{DATA:alis_class}?\],\[%{IPV4:alis_clientIp}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_threadid}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_sessionid}?\],%{INT:alis_companyid}?,\[%{DATA:alis_requesttoken}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_activity}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_screen}?\],\[%{INT:alis_action}?\],\[%{INT:alis_region}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_nextscreen}?\],%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}?" 
      "logMessage" =>["REQUEST_END, %{WORD:duration}"]
    }
  }
 

}
```

How I can extract this number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks really close to solution.
I guess there is just a typo on the "logMessage" grok line.
Replace this line :

```
  "logMessage" =>["REQUEST_END, %{WORD:duration}"]
```

By this one :

```
  "logMessage" =>["REQUEST_END,%{INT:duration}"]
```

The **WORD** pattern doesn't catch the integer "string", with **INT** grok's pattern you must catch your *duration* field, and there is a space that not be here.

And you must set 2 different grok filter to be able to parse 2 steps so your filter part in your logstash configuration file :

```
  filter{
    grok {
        match => { 
          "message" => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:alis_timestamp}\],\[%{LOGLEVEL:alis_loglevel}\s*\],\[%{DATA:alis_class}?\],\[%{IPV4:alis_clientIp}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_threadid}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_sessionid}?\],%{INT:alis_companyid}?,\[%{DATA:alis_requesttoken}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_activity}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_screen}?\],\[%{INT:alis_action}?\],\[%{INT:alis_region}?\],\[%{DATA:alis_nextscreen}?\],%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}?" 
          }
    }
    grok {
        match => {   
          "logMessage" =>["REQUEST_END,%{INT:duration}"]
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried your solution.. but the field duration isn't created at all...there are the fields that I have:  alis_class
alis_clientIp
alis_loglevel
alis_requesttoken
alis_sessionid
alis_threadid
alis_timestamp
logMessage
message 
path........any idea? thanks

Comment: Yes sorry, I've updated my answer, now it must work, and there is a space in the logMessage pattern that not be here.